# Why do so many React/Flux tutorials advocate multiple stores?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I've been looking at the Baobab library and am very attracted to the "single-tree" approach, which I interpret as essentially a single store. But so many Flux tutorials seem to advocate many stores, even a "store per entity."  Having multiple stores seems to me to present all kinds of concurrency issues.  My question is, why is single store a bad idea?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded and the one way data binding advocated by React and implemented via Flux you will not have concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what want to do and how big is your project. There are a few reason why having several stores is a good idea:

1. If your project is not so small afterall you may end up with a huge 2000/3000lines store and you don't want that. That's the point of writing modules in general. You want to avoid files bigger than 1000lines (and below 500 is even nicer :) ).
2. Writing everything in one store makes that you can't enjoy the dependency management with the dispatcher using the waitFor function.It's gonna be harder to check dependencies and potential circular dependencies between your models (since they are all in one store). I would suggest you take a look at https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/chat.html for that.
3. It's harder to read. With several store you can at one glance figure out what type of data you have and with a constant file for the dispatcher events you can see all your events.

So it's possible to keep everything in one store and it may work perfectly but if your project grows you may regret it badly and rewrite everything in several modules/store. Just my opinion I prefer to have clean modules and data workflows.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I totally agree with this. I've tried to keep a bunch of "related" code in one file before with another framework and it was absolutely terrible. Although all my functions are tiny, I couldn't find any of them from a glance and I quickly forgot what was in that file. I think it's much easier to run into this issue than concurrency issues with stores. Also, I do reuse some stores for closely related projects so it's necessary for me to separate them for more efficient dependency management.

Comment: That's a good point! If you want to reuse data store code in different projects with similar data, then separate, more concise stores will have its benefits

Comment: Indeed. "The value of separation of concerns is simplifying development and maintenance of computer programs. When concerns are well-separated, individual sections can be reused, as well as developed and updated independently. "-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, working with a single store is definitely not a bad idea. It has some advantages, such as:

1. A single store to access all data can make it easier to query and make relationships about different pieces of data. Using multiple stores can make this a little bit more difficult (definitely not impossible though).
2. It will be easier to make atomic updates to the application state (aka data store).

But the way you implement the Flux pattern will influence on your experience with a single data store. The folks at Facebook have been experimenting with this and it seems like they encourage the use of a single data store with their new Relay+GraphQL stuff (read more about it here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html).

Comment: But the problem is that relay&graphql are not open-source yet so this implementation is not an option yet.

Modules are still the best option I think.

Comment: They've been recently made open-source (https://github.com/facebook/graphql & https://github.com/facebook/relay). But I mentioned them just as an idea. There are easier ways to get started with the single data store approach. If you feel like it's appropriate to use or migrate to Relay/GraphQL, then give it a shot :)

Comment: interesting. However I woudl'nt advise single store with the classic flux pattern.